# Scaling selected Inkscape path nodes to exact percentage. How?

Tags: inkscape, vector

Seems like a simple thing. If the answer exists elsewhere please help me with the link.

There exists a possibility to scale an object or a group to a specific percentage. For this one can use e.g. <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to get transformation dialog and set scale there for X and Y dimensions.

How to do the same thing for selected path nodes only?

There exists a possibility to enable onscreen handles for selected nodes and resize by dragging, but I was unable to find the way for precise scaling say to 200%.

E.g. Take this star
[image]
and scale only the group of selected nodes to precise percentage
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you share an example image showing what you are actually trying to achieve by doing this?  There may be a better way to do it.  The percentage scaling in the Transform panel won't work on a selected segment of a closed path. You may need to break the path apart, scale, then reassemble. Other possibilities which might work are to design something using a grid, and enable snap to grid. It's also possible to add extrra nodes to a segment (exactly in the middle) using the Insert new nodes button, delete a segment, move other nodes, and join nodes.

Comment: I am unaware of any functionality within Inkscape GUI that specifies the scale numerically for the selected nodes. But I think it is a good candidate for an extension to fill this gap (you can create one if you're familiar with Python).

Comment: Thanks, already looking into writing extensions.

Concerning images I'll add them. But I think the answer is - there is no such out-of-the-box functionality.

Comment: @FedorPetrov - there are methods to avoid such a problem, but not with the functionality you describe. As it stands this is bit like [an XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  That's why I suggest you show us an example of what you are actually trying to do. There may be a better way to create what you want that doesn't involve scaling. Can't really tell you without seeing something though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there no such functionality. Percentage scaling in the Transform panel is only available for a whole path (i.e. a whole object). It can't be used separately on selected nodes.

Anyway, if you want a solution, here's one possible method.

1. Duplicate the shape and scale 150% and use the duplicate as a guide
2. Move each node individually using snapping to nodes.
3. The curves won't match exactly though, so you may need to tweak the Bézier handles manually. Use the outline view for accuracy and zoom in.

[image]

Afterwards, you can delete the shape you used as a guide. Also I note that the curves are an added complication here. Even if you could select and scale nodes by percentage, it would still be a problem since the angles of the Bézier handles would change even if they were scaled accurately.